# Is there an environment variable that is set for Unity?

Tags: unity, environment-variables

My script needs to be able to detect if the Unity is being used on top of the Gnome DE. The only other way I can think of is basically seeing if the config file is there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Ubuntu 11.10

1. Ubuntu session (compiz/unity)

   ```
   DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu
   GDMSESSION=ubuntu
   XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity
   ```
2. Ubuntu 2D session (metacity):

   ```
   DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu-2d
   GDMSESSION=ubuntu-2d
   XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity
   ```
3. Gnome session (gnome-shell):

   ```
   DESKTOP_SESSION=gnome-shell
   GDMSESSION=gnome-shell
   XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME
   ```
4. Gnome Classic session (metacity):

   ```
   DESKTOP_SESSION=gnome-classic
   GDMSESSION=gnome-classic
   XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME
   ```
5. Gnome Classic no effects session (metacity):

   ```
   DESKTOP_SESSION=gnome-fallback
   GDMSESSION=gnome-fallback
   XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME
   ```

#### Ubuntu 11.04

1. Ubuntu session (compiz/unity):

   ```
   DESKTOP_SESSION=gnome
   GDMSESSION=gnome
   ```
2. Ubuntu Classic session (compiz):

   ```
   DESKTOP_SESSION=gnome-classic
   GDMSESSION=gnome-classic
   ```
3. Ubuntu Classic no effects session (metacity):

   ```
   DESKTOP_SESSION=gnome-2d
   GDMSESSION=gnome-2d
   ```

Comment: When I am running Unity, I seem to have values "gnome" for those variables and XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP is not found. Using the env command, I find COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE=ubuntu.

Comment: @P4L: my answer is based on 11.10, I missed the tag 11.04 in the question :(

Comment: @P4L: I updated my answer